# The GetLegendGraphic query does not return legends for the specified bbox value

Tags: geoserver, wms, getlegendgraphic

I have a GetLegendGraphic request like:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WMS&request=GetLegendGraphic&width=19&height=19&layer=Workspace:Layer&rule=&bbox=8126200.9087728467,9581252.8025055025,9577653.389397664,10414397.006185452&srcwidth=2743&srcheight=1574&srs=EPSG:3857&legend_options=hideEmptyRules:true&format=image/png.
```

Layer is based on PostGIS. GeoServer version 2.19.

I cannot get the legend in this BBOX, although I get the correct image when I request an image by GetMap. The GetLegendGraphic and GetMap queries are based on the same principle of filtering features, as I understand it, but it is not clear why then they give different results.

There are 4 screen shots. BBOX in `GetMapCorrect` gives me correct legend in `GetLegendGraphicCorrect` query. BBOX in `GetMapIncorrect` gives me error legend in `GetLegendGraphicIncorrect`.

**GetLegendGraphicCorrect:**

Request

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WMS&request=GetLegendGraphic&format=image/png&width=19&height=19&layer=Workspace:Layer&rule=&bbox=7830826.700968759,9960757.157649865,9252323.14903124,10776706.38235013&srcwidth=2743&srcheight=1574&srs=EPSG:3857&legend_options=hideEmptyRules:true
```

Response

[image: geoserver-GetLegendGraphicCorrect]

**GetLegendGraphicIncorrect:**

Request

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WMS&request=GetLegendGraphic&width=19&height=19&layer=Workspace:Layer&rule=&bbox=8126200.9087728467,9581252.8025055025,9577653.389397664,10414397.006185452&srcwidth=2743&srcheight=1574&srs=EPSG:3857&legend_options=hideEmptyRules:true&format=image/png
```

Response

[image: geoserver-GetLegendGraphicIncorrect]

**GetMapCorrect:**

Request

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=Workspace:Layer&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&WIDTH=2743&HEIGHT=1574&BBOX=7830826.700968759,9960757.157649865,9252323.14903124,10776706.38235013
```

Response

[image: GetMapCorrect]

**GetMapIncorrect:**

Request

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=Workspace:Layer&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&WIDTH=2743&HEIGHT=1574&BBOX=8126200.9087728467,9581252.8025055025,9577653.389397664,10414397.006185452
```

Response

[image: GetMapIncorrect]

Comment: What does a GetLegendGraphic request with no BBOX provide?  It's difficult to see in your GetMap requests as the dots are so small, but your 'correct' response, doesn't seem to match the symbology on the 'correct' map.  One is a red dot the other is  a black dot in a red circle

Comment: As an aside both GetLegendGraphic requests seem to be missing both the WMS version (version=1.3.0&) and the SLD version (sld_version=1.1.0&) GetLegendGraphic is an SLD operation, and for completeness (TRANSPARENT=TRUE&) the values for transparent are TRUE/FALSE (case is important for values in the OGC OWS standards, though software may be lax)

Comment: Without a zone, the legend is one element.

Comment: I am using the GeoServer, thus the versions are specified by default. But I tried changing the versions, it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just need turn off "Support on the fly geometry simplification".

Answer (score 1):

A contextual GetLegendGraphic request doesn't give you a legend **in** a bounding box, it gives a legend **for** a bounding box (of a specific GetMap request).

A standard GetLegendGraphic request gives you a legend that represents all the styled attributes in a WMS layer, if you're looking at the whole map then that might be appropriate, but if you are zoomed in to a small area you may only want to see a legend that represents the values shown in the map, this is where a contextual GetLegendGraphic request is useful.  Assuming the server software supports it, you can submit the GetLegendGraphic request with the same BBOX as the GetMap request for the area of interest.

Comment: Yes, I am doing it, but I am not getting legend for features that are in the bbox. And I am sure that they are there, because the GetMap request gives the correct image, filtering in the Postgis too.